# Making a container grow on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jQuery function that takes the current height and width of a link then makes it grow by whatever amount of px I set. I don't have much so far and I'm completely lost.

```
$('.absolute_img_links').hover(function(){

    var link_height = $('.absolute_img_links').outerHeight();
    var link_width = $('.absolute_img_links').width();

});
```

I know how to get the current height and width but I don't know how to basically say height of .absolute_img_links = link_height + 10px in jQuery

Comment: so you set the width and height....

Comment: Note that if you increase the height and width on hover, you will also need to _decrease_ the dimensions on blur unless you want ever increasing links.

Answer (score 1):

same functions do the job:

```
$('.absolute_img_links').hover(function(){

    var link_height = $('.absolute_img_links').outerHeight();
    $('.absolute_img_links').outerHeight(link_height + 10);
    var link_width = $('.absolute_img_links').width();
    $('.absolute_img_links').width(link_width + 10);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you need you can pass a function to the `height()` and `width()` functions. In these functions you receive the current value, to which you can just add the `10px` as required.

Note that `hover()` fires twice, once for `mouseenter` and once for `mouseleave`. Also, you don't reset the size of the element, so it just gets larger and larger on successive hovering. To fix this, amend your logic so that you attach the event handlers separately instead of one `hover()` call so you can increase/decrease the size as needed. Try this:

```js
$('.absolute_img_links').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this)
    .height(function(i, height) { return height + 10; })
    .width(function(i, width) { return width + 10; });
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this)
    .height(function(i, height) { return height - 10; })
    .width(function(i, width) { return width - 10; });
});
```

```css
.absolute_img_links {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="absolute_img_links">
  Hover me!
</div>
```

Also note that you can implement a pure CSS version of this which has the exact same effect, although simply adds `padding` to the right and bottom of the element, instead of changing the width/height. Try this:

```css
.absolute_img_links {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
.absolute_img_links:hover {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="absolute_img_links">
  Hover me!
</div>
```

Using the above method you could even keep the text centralised too, by adding a consistent `5px` padding around the entire element.

Comment: nice catch of `hover` fires twice.+1. deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `height()` and `width()` you can simply add 10 to the values you have found to increase the height/width of the container.

```js
$('.absolute_img_links').hover(function() {

  //var link_height = $('.absolute_img_links').outerHeight();
  //var link_width = $('.absolute_img_links').width();
  //Changed to $(this)
  var link_height = $(this).outerHeight();
  var link_width = $(this).width();
  $(this).height(link_height + 10);
  $(this).width(link_width + 10);

});
```

```css
.absolute_img_links {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="absolute_img_links"></div>
```

Comment: You should probably use `this` for all of them inside the hover

Comment: @epascarello good point, I just copy-pasted OP's code, but yeah, `$(this)` would definitely be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**I know you asked for jQuery but...**

This is trivial (and more flexible) in CSS:

```css
.absolute_img_links img { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.absolute_img_links:hover img { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="absolute_img_links"><img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" /></a>
<a href="#" class="absolute_img_links"><img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" /></a>
```